# How do I get pretty URLs (remove #) while using ui-router.?

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I have already tried $locationProvider and base href tag in my head of my index.html file. But was getting 404 error while rendering my views. I think it is something with my app.use method of Express in app.js file.

This is my folder structure of this project. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFPlk.png

This is my app.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000...');
```

This is my script.js file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
    controller  : 'homeController'
})
    .state('posts', {
    url: '/posts',
    templateUrl : 'views/posts.html',
    controller  : 'postsController'
})
    .state('radio', {
    url: '/radio',
    templateUrl : 'views/radio.html',
    controller  : 'radioController'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
myApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) { 
$scope.title = 'Hello.'; 
});
myApp.controller('radioController', function($scope) { 
$scope.message = 'Look! I am an radio page.'; 
});
```

This is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WISS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a ui-sref="home">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="posts">POSTS</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="radio">RADIO</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Angular place `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in your `myApp.config` block.

Then for express add this before `app.listen(3000)`

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: That works ! Thanks alot !